# Вложенные пространства имен только "отображают" файловую структуру?

Tags: php

Мануал читал, но осталось пара вопросов.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что **пространство имен это фактически уникальный идентификатор класса и более ничего?**

Например

```
<?php
namespace MyPHPProject;
class Strings
{}


<?php
namespace MyPHPProject\classes; 
// Файл Strings.php лежит в папке MyPHPProject\classes\
// Согласно стандарту, мы задаем пространство имен вида имя проекта\имя папки
class Strings
{}


<?php
namespace Abracadabra\Abra\cadabra\NoFolder\AnyText; 
// Файл Strings.php лежит в папке MyPHPProject\classes\
// Но мы решили просто написать какое то пространство имен-текст который первым пришел в голову
class Strings
{}
```

То есть вложенность namespace MyPHPProject и namespace  MyPHPProject\classes никак не влияет на вызов этих классов.

**Вложенность это только способ показать (спроецировать) файловую систему проекта - подсказать программисту где лежат эти файлы?
Или вложенность как то ещё влияет на вызов классов?**

Если неймспейс - это просто способ уникально идентифицировать класс, тогда не понятно **зачем нужны относительные и абсолютные пути?**

```
<?php

include_once __DIR__.'/Strings.php';

use MyPHPProject\Strings;

$strings=new Strings();
//$strings=new MyPHPProject\Strings(); // Ещё один вариант использования
//$strings=new \MyPHPProject\Strings(); // Ещё один вариант использования PHPStorm подсказывает, что \ не нужно
```

В PHP абсолютный путь создается при помощи **DIR** т.к. относительный путь, при вызове скрипта разным способом, рассчитывается относительно разных "объектов" - скрипт прекрасно работающий в браузере не найдет\подключит скрипты при вызове из cron.

А тут это зачем? Зачем пишут MyPHPProject\Strings и \MyPHPProject\Strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> пространство имен это фактически уникальный идентификатор класса

Вполне можно рассматривать это с такой позиции. Например в том же Windows, если в папке `d:\Downloads\` лежит файл `Приколы.doc`, то система считает, что его имя на самом деле `d:\\Downloads\\Приколы.doc`. Таким образом система считает файлы с одинаковым названием и расширением, но лежащие в разных папках - разными файлами.

> namespace Abracadabra\Abra\cadabra\NoFolder\AnyText;
> // Файл Strings.php лежит в папке MyPHPProject\classes
> // Но мы решили просто написать какое то пространство имен-текст который первым пришел в голову

Да, такое может быть, используя загрузчики, типа `composer`. Там можно задать папки или файлы немного кастомные, так скажем, у которых пространство имён никак не совпадает с физическим расположением в системе. Однако стОит понимать, что общая практика склоняется всё же к совпадению путей в пространстве имён и пути в проекте, именно для того, чтобы **подсказать программисту где лежат эти файлы**.  Поэтому часто загрузчик делают по `PSR-4` и в таком случае если указать выдуманный из головы namespace - то получишь ошибку `Class 'app\models\test\Testy1' not found`

> вложенность как то ещё влияет на вызов классов?

Вложенность может влиять некоторым образом на производительность. Но не значительно. Как правило, при использовании автозагрузчика эти файлы могут быть перечислены у него в специальном файле, типа такого

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'ArithmeticError' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-php70/Resources/stubs/ArithmeticError.php',
    'AssertionError' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-php70/Resources/stubs/AssertionError.php',
    'Codeception\\Exception\\ExternalUrlException' => $vendorDir . '/codeception/lib-innerbrowser/src/Codeception/Exception/ExternalUrlException.php',
    'Codeception\\Lib\\Connector\\Yii2' => $vendorDir . '/codeception/module-yii2/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Yii2.php',
    'Codeception\\Lib\\Connector\\Yii2\\ConnectionWatcher' => $vendorDir . '/codeception/module-yii2/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Yii2/ConnectionWatcher.php',
    'Codeception\\Lib\\Connector\\Yii2\\FixturesStore' => $vendorDir . '/codeception/module-yii2/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Yii2/FixturesStore.php',
);
```

и он просто будет их подключать в цикле в коде через `require`.  В целом все классы требуют подключения через `require` и на это тратится время. Однако, как правило, оно не столь значительное, чтобы сильно влиять на производительность.

> зачем нужны относительные и абсолютные пути?

Относительный путь удобно использовать во вложенности. Если есть класс по пути `app\models\test\Test` и `app\models\test\Test2`, то в первом достаточно будет написать `use Test2`, а не `use app\models\test\Test2`.

Абсолютный - я бы сказал, что нужен больше для предохранения от случайного подключения неправильного класса. Например

```
namespace My\Other\NS {
    use \My\Other as Other; 
    use Other\NS as Duh; // Будет искать \My\Other\NS
}

namespace My\Other\NS {
    use My\Other as Other; 
    use Other\NS as Duh; // Будет искать \My\Other\NS\My\Other\NS
}
```

Такое может возникнуть например, когда есть "несколько корней". Например у используемого фреймворка, который лежит в папке `vendor`, может всё начинаться с `Yii` или `Sympony`, а в приложении всё начинается с `app`. В таком случае может произойти следующее:

```
namespace app\controllers;

class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function actionTest() {
        echo Yii::$app->user->isGuest;
    }
}
```

В этом случае будет ошибка `Class 'app\controllers\Yii' not found` потому что путь относительный. Однако если поставить путь "от корня", абсолютный, вот так:

```
echo \Yii::$app->user->isGuest;
```

то всё будет работать.

> А тут это зачем? Зачем пишут MyPHPProject\Strings и \MyPHPProject\Strings?

Во-первых - см. текст выше. Второе - это может быть сделано для перестраховки, чтобы наверняка подключить нужный класс, а не бояться, что подключится класс из относительного пути. Но как правило все классы подключают в `use`, если нужно назначают алиасы, а уже в коде ниже пишут всё без обратной черты. Код становится чище.

Обратную черту перед классом любят ставить по многим причинам (мне лично кажется это избыточным), например для встроенных функций PHP, типа `new \PDO` или `\strlen(...)`. Чтобы отличить свои написанные классы, от встроенных.

Ну и если есть конфликт имён (например при наследовании класса из другого неймспейса.), тоже можно это использовать.

```
namespace foo;

class Bar extends \baz\Bar { }
```

Однако я лично предпочитаю задать алиас и писать так:

```
namespace foo;
use baz\Bar as CoreBar;

class Bar extends CoreBar { }
```

Comment: Про пути не понял. Путь в неймспейсе - это идентификатор.
Просто пишем include_once __DIR__.'/MyClass.php'; и use ЧтоТамНаписаноВНеймспейсе_MyClass.
Зачем \? В use у MyClass никаких \ впереди нет. Мы же не рассчитываем пути как в HTML или PHP. У нас путь - условная абракадабра, которая только для вида, для удобства поиска, совпадает с расположением файла в директории.

Comment: Я не понял что ты спрашиваешь.... про какие именно "\"  ты спрашиваешь. Тебе надо переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Есть 2 вида путей use \MyClass\Strings; и use MyClass\Strings; Начинающиеся с \ и без неё.  В чем тут смысл и когда их использовать? Я понимаю относительные и абсолютные пути в PHP/HTML. А как это работает в пространстве имен?

Comment: Я это написал в ответе вполне понятно, начиная со слов  "зачем нужны относительные и абсолютные пути?" и вниз по тексту. Причём с примерами

Comment: Я читал много раз. Но я не понимаю. Я также прочитал статью про упрощение путей, выполнил пример - не работает.
https://php.zone/c/63f5bca5dc37f255355034

Comment: Что именно не ясно? Вопрос: зачем ставят черту. Ответ: визуально отделить встроенные функции от собственно написанных .....а также если есть конфликт имён при наследовании класса из другого неймспейса..... что в этих словах не понятно? Они не несут никакой двоякости или ещё что-то

Comment: *"выполнил пример - не работает. php.zone/c/63f5bca5dc37f255355034"* --- а что там должно работать? там же кривой код

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример с фреймворком (cм. правку) Думаю, это самый основной вариант когда нужно указать абсолютный путь. А также, как я писал, в примере с перестраховкой про `use \My\Other as Other;`...... хотя опять же.... если использовать пути через `use`, то там обратный слэш в начале не обязателен. т.к. автоматом они будут конвертироваться в абсолютные пути...точнее там других путей указать нельзя

Comment: Я понимаю что такое абсолютный путь. Я не понимаю, что такое относительный путь. Только что увидел, что в моем примере кривой код (ctrl+c песочница скушала все слеши). Переделал в нормальной песочнице.  https://onlinephp.io/c/b032a Почему я не могу использовать use addons\MyClass1;?

Comment: Относительный путь - путь, относительно текущего неймспейса... Например Class1 с пространством имён `my\test` и Class2 с пространством имён `my\test\hello`.  В первом классе в любом методе можно написать `new hello\Class2()` и в итоге будет произведён поиск второго класса относительно пространства имени первого класса плюс `hello`, а если бы был обратный слэш то поиск бы был в пространстве имён `hello` а не `my\test\hello'`.....то есть относительные пути я бы сказал применимы в методах, а не в use

Comment: Единственное, когда можно использовать относительные пути в use это только если их группировать: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.group   ..... https://wiki.php.net/rfc/group_use_declarations

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Зачем нужно пространство имен - чтобы сгруппировать функционал и избежать конфликта имен, с помощью данного подхода реализуется один из основных принципов ООП, полиморфизм.

> И нет, пространство имен никак не связано с файловой структурой
> проекта, хотя часто его с ней соотносят для удобства поиска и
> понимания подключаемых классов.

В действительности связано, т.к. с помощью него же как-то происходит автозагрузка классов.

***а.*** Через composer, оный будет использовать стандарт PSR-4, в котором есть жеткий регламент привязки к директориям, если это проигнорировать, получите ошибку, т.к. по PSR-4, namespace = структуре директорий, но только от коря проекта.

***б.*** Реализовать автозагрузку классов самому, тут как уже все поняли, можно накостылить хоть массив [ключь => значение], перебирать его и использовать в своем проекте таким образом любые пространства имен, которые уже никак не будут биться в структурой директорий.

**2.** Абсолютный путь - это хардкод относительно корня вашей файловой структуры на физической машине, вида: `/home/you/php/index.php` или же относительно текущей директории `__DIR__./php/index.php` и существует, чтобы сказать допустим вашему серверу, куда смотреть, в какой директории искать скрипты. *В действительности, вариаций таких путей множество, напирмер, очень распространен в фреймворках от коря проекта, т.е. путь до коря проекта находится динамически, а по проекту хардкод: `PathHelper::getProjectDir./public/index.php`.*

Но представьте, если бы вы в каждом своем скрипте аналогично захардкодили пути допустим к файлам/картинкам, а после чего еще и решили перенести свой проект в другую директорию, будете переписывать все пути? Вот для второго кейса в пределах проекта нужно использовать относительные пути, т.к. структура директорий в пределах проекта у вас будет одна и та же, даже после переноса, в таком случае, смело подключаете файлы и ссылаетесь на них относительно текущего скрипта.

Comment: Чуть несостыковки есть)  *"пространство имен никак не связано с файловой структурой проекта"*   и *"Абсолютный путь - это хардкод относительно вашей файловой структуры на физической машине, т.е. он будет всегда вида /home/you/php/index.php...."*

Comment: @Borislav Не соглашусь. Вы сравниваете php и html. Как вы могли заметить, в PHP все пути к файлам пишутся через __DIR__. То есть они все абсолютные. Но ведь можно написать и include_once Class.php если этот файл лежит рядом и это будет работать. Будет, но не везде. Веб сервер найдет этот файл, а вот cron нет. Они ищут относительные пути относительно разных директорий.
В то же время в HTML, почти всегда используются относительные пути. Потому что данный файл, его пути, обрабатываются исключительно веб сервером (он нам отдает контент).

Comment: @Иван Разумеется нет, я не сравниваю php и html. У вас имеется заблуждение, относительно того, что cron и web-server ищут относительно разных директорий, у них просто разные директории выполнения, т.к. сервер вы изначально конфигурируете, допустим на `/var/www/html`, он под капотом сделает cd на эту директорию и выполнит ваши скрипты оттуда, а `cron`, по дефолту (если не переопределить в $PATH) делает это из `/home/*your_user*/`. Аналогично, вы говорите, если "выполнить из консоли", так вы выйдите на директорию назад `../` и попробуйте запустить оттуда свой скрипт.

Comment: @Иван Тем самым хочу сказать, что не всегда и тем более не везде используют __DIR__, т.к. это даже в целях написания кода более энергозатратно, чем `chdir(__DIR__)` (сменит директорию на директорию текущего скрипта (делать подобное нужно в index.php разумеется)) и далее везде использовать относительные пути.

Comment: @Borislav composer\autoload_static.php 1096 использований __DIR__ , Laravel 6955 использований, Joomla 2728 использований. Мне всё же кажется, что использование DIR в пути это дефолт. И что делать, если не возможно (а может и не нужно) изменить переменную $PATH? На хостинге нет доступа к конфигу, это не VDS. А что будет, если в один прекрасный день кто то решит использовать часть вашего проекта в своем проекте? Зачем что то придумывать, когда можно писать путь с DIR и знать что всегда и везде всё будет работать.

Comment: @Иван данной, приведенной статистикой хотите покрыть все кейсы в разработке или что-то еще из этого нужно уловить? Никто вам и не доказывает, что использование DIR менее рекомендуется или что-то около этого, вам лишь указали, что есть другой вариант. При автоподгрузке классов, относительные пути придется резолвить на ходу, а абсолютные уже зарезовлены, таким образом это просто легче, и это говорит только в пользу того, что под каждую задачу есть свое более подходящее решение и АБСОЛЮТНЫЕ пути по дефолту как вы сказали или канонично не всегда подойдут.